# slideToggle("slow") not working as I want to be

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

http://jsfiddle.net/T8t2r/294/

In the above the example when I click on the parent class, it should slide down the child class, but it is not doing so properly. Can someone help me with it ?

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function getChildren($row) {
        var children = [];
        while($row.next().hasClass('child')) {
             children.push($row.next());
             $row = $row.next();
        }            
        return children;
    }        

    $('.parent').on('click', function() {

        var children = getChildren($(this));
        $.each(children, function() {
            $(this).toggle();
        })
    });

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$(".parent").click(function(){

    $(this).nextUntil(".parent").toggle();

})
```

})

Comment: given the same effect u can try in the jsfiddle

Comment: now I understand your issue. Unfortunately table rows cannot be animated. You will need to wrap your cell contents with a div, then animate those divs to closely achieve this kind of effects

Comment: could you please edit the code in the jsfiddle n provide me the link, I am not so much familiar to jquery

Comment: I did solve most of the problem as you said, but not all the child elements are coming in the result, looks like some minor error here or there could you please give it a look, http://jsfiddle.net/T8t2r/299/

Answer (score 0):

And what about add there simple speed to the toogle function:

```
$('.parent').on('click', function() {

    var children = getChildren($(this));
    $.each(children, function() {
        $(this).toggle(1000);
    })
});
```

But as mentioned in comments, the rows can't be animated and the whole effect looks ugly. You will need to add divs there.

Edit: [Here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is more details about the jQuery .toggle() function